# Current Mirror - Supply Dependence

Tags: mosfet, analog, current-mirror

I have a question about one of the current mirrors introduced in the "Bandgap References" chapter of Razavi's Design of Analog ICs.

He has this:

[image]

My confusion is about Equation 12.1.

I know that for a basic current  mirror, $$I_{out} = (W/L)(M_2)/(W/L)(M_1) * I_{ref}$$ 
is valid.

**From the looks of it, he seems to have ignored the voltage drop across R1 and just taken it to be the supply voltage Vdd.  Shouldn't there be another term?**

Here is my answer:

[image]

Comment: He's not calculating Iout, he's calculating the change in Iout wrt Vdd or dIout/dVdd.

Comment: @JohnD Ah yes. Thanks very much. I differentiated by Iout function and got the same answer. (had to add the 1/gm resistance).